# Select unique rows of foreign key and last timestamp

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with a table with these schema:

```
CREATE TABLE register (
    register_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    mould_id VARCHAR, 
    timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (register_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(mould_id) REFERENCES mould (mould_id)
)
```

Timestamp is incremental integer, so bigger timestamp means more recent time.

I want to get last register (more recent/bigger timestamp) for each mould_id. Is it possible to get this using an SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by mould_id:

```
select *, max(timestamp) from register group by mould_id
```

Comment: Thx for teaching me something today: 6th point of the 3.7.11 update => http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE mould_id = :mould_id ORDER_BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I want one single query to get last register for each mould, not one query for each mould_id

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3ff366/6
First you can group data by mould_id and select the last timestamp (max).
Then select data from the register table where mould_id and timestamp correspond

```
SELECT *
  FROM register r
  JOIN ( SELECT mould_id
              , MAX(timestamp) timestamp
           FROM register
          GROUP BY mould_id ) d ON r.mould_id  = d.mould_id
                               AND r.timestamp = d.timestamp
```

Comment: this is working, but I prefer @jesús-muñoz answer because it includes only one select and no joins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if SQL Lite does support that syntax but in postgreSQL you would do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.mould_id) * FROM register r ORDER BY r.mould_id, timestamp ASC
```